# tortoisesvn marks all newly added files as "non-versioned"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Today I found that whatever new files added to my repository will not be picked up by tortoisesvn.

[image]

There are no ignore patterns for *.cs files (either globally or locally). Yet any new file is marked as **non-versioned**.

[image]

Now, I can only include all newly added files manually. This problem is driving me crazy. Hope someone can point out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell Subversion to begin tracking the file by running `svn add` or via `Add` command in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I remembered that once I added a folder to SVN and newly added files under this folder will be automatically added. I didn't realize I should add the folder every time manually. Anyway, maybe my memory was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can install the AnkhSVN Extension, and this will allow you to add the file to your SVN repository directly within Visual Studio. This saves you having to separately add to SVN via the Tortoise client or via Windows Explorer.

You can even configure the extension to auto-add new files to SVN !